# Export project gives empty assets

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets

I have a problem when I try to export a projet to an another computer (both with Unity version 5.0.1f).

I use this path `Export Package -> All -> Select Dependencies` and when I import the project I select custom package. Everything is imported without any problem, except the assets which are visually empty in Unity even if the file has the same Ko as the model. So when I drag and drop them in the project to test them, nothing is visible, nor in the inspector or in the preview.

How can I import a project keeping the assets visible?

Comment: 5.0.1f1 Personal version

Comment: I've never used the Export Package option. I just copy the game folder over into the other computer's unity game directory.

Comment: I think I tried this but I don't remember why it didn't work. I'll try again, thanks.